Why is the centrifugal force multiplied by $\sin$ here?
I'm currently studying for an exam and wondering what the visual interpretation of this question would be.

It's a multiple part question and the first question was describing the equilibrium angle of the point mass. After some dynamics it's found that it can be described by $\cos\theta = g/(\omega^2 R$). I get it up until here, but when they ask for the equation of motion, I do not understand why it is $mR\ddot\theta = -mg\sin\theta + m\omega^2 R \sin\theta\cos\theta$. My difficulty is in understanding why the centrifugal force has to be $m\omega^2 R\sin\theta\cos\theta$. To be exact, the sine term.

There is no concept of ‘sin’ in physics.

The centrifugal force is in the horizontal direction on the diagram. Given that the distance of the particle from the center of the axis of rotation is $R\sin(\theta)$, the magnitude of the centrifugal force is $m\omega^2R\sin(\theta)$. From this, the component of the centrifugal force in the $\theta$ direction is $m\omega^2R\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$.

This is the free body diagram

from the sum of the forces towards the tangent $~e_t~$, you obtain the equation of motion
